# UITableView viewForHeaderInSection- autoreleased view crashes app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UIViewController` that implements `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`.  I am customizing the section headers using the viewForHeaderInSection method:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UILabel *label = sectionHeaderLabel();

switch (section) {
    case 0:
        label.text = @"";
        break;
    case 1:
        label.text = @"Points";
        break;
    case 2:
        label.text = @"Problems";
        break;
    default:
        label.text = @"";
        break;
}

// Create header view and add label as a subview
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[view addSubview:label];
[label release];

return view;
```

}

The compiler complains that I have a memory leak related to view and I realize that I should be autoreleasing it.  But when I do, my app crashes when I hit the back button to pop the view off the navigation controller.

What's up with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be related to label instead of view.

Does the sectionHeaderLabel() method return an autoreleased label object? If so you shouldn't be explicitly releasing label after adding it as a subview to view.

Try removing [label release]; and returning [view autorelease];

Comment: If this is a new project, and you aren't supporting iOS 3.x, you might want to try switching on ARC. It will save you making these kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) before proceeding with further development - it will save you a lot of grief.

Clang (not the compiler) is complaining because you are returning a +1 retained object (unmatched init) from a method whose name indicates it returns an autoreleased object.

Then (as Nick states), you are probably returning an autoreleased object from sectionLabelHeader().  The over-retain of "view" is thus covering up an over-release of "label".

Finally, why are you using a C function to return a UILabel *?  It's legal AFAIK, but rather unorthodox.  It wouldn't surprise me if that will trip up Clang as well.  It will certainly cause problems if/when you move to automatic reference counting (ARC).  I would recommend you use a method instead, or a class method if you are going for a factory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using methods in place of C-functions.  I'm wondering: if I have a custom label with all sorts of pre-set properties - font size, text color, etc - that I use across numerous views, is it better to sub-class UILabel, extend UILabel using categories, or simply call a factory method?

Comment: I'd say only subclass if you need to *override* a method.  If all you are doing is setting properties, a category on UILabel is probably the way to go.  Just make sure to prefix (well, personally I prefer suffixes for readability) the method so you don't clash with any present or future private methods.  Something like + labelWithCustomProperties_JAG {}.